# How to lock placement of notification windows in Tunnelblick on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, openvpn, mac

Tunnelblick connection/disconnection notification windows are great, but for some reason they've annoyingly started appearing in the middle of my screen instead of off to the right.   Every time I drag them to the top right corner, they only stay there until the next time they popup.

**How do I lock them in the top right corner?**

PS:  I've looked through the documentation, particularly in the [Preferences That Control What The User Sees](https://tunnelblick.net/cz33Prefs.html#preferences-that-control-what-the-user-sees), but none of these `notificationWindow` or any others in the documentation lock the notification windows.

Comment: Restarting the system worked for me